# Terraform does not assigns public IP address to EC2 instance upon creation

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

Terraform does not assigns public IP address to EC2 instance upon creation

Public IP address get assigned when created manually through EC2 console

Subnets are in Public network only, Please help

Comment: would you be kind to share some terraform code used along with error messages if any? Thank you

Comment: have you set the associate_public_ip_address attribute to true in your aws_instance resource? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#associate_public_ip_address `(Optional) Whether to associate a public IP address with an instance in a VPC.`

Answer (score 1):

when creating a subnet, add this line in ya terraform file.

map_public_ip_on_launch = true

```
# AWS VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
    cidr_block = "172.16.0.0/16"

    tags = {
      Name = "tf-example"
    }
}

# AWS SUBNET ATTACHED TO THE AWS VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "172.16.10.0/24"
  availability_zone = "af-south-1a"
# this line give you a public IP address
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name  = "tf-example"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer is no longer accurate. It's now:

```
associate_public_ip_address = true
```